# Minecraft Better Together update on Kindle HD stops Broadcast to LAN

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

since the update my kids cannot join each others worlds over our LAN. The Broadcast to LAN option has disappeared, and in its place looks like I have to get an xbox live account (we dont even have an Xbox), then create their child accounts, and then get them to sign in to use Minecraft, and then have to use the external servers. Is this avoidable, is there a way to just continue playing over LAN? (seems like a hell of a change and waste of time when they don't need any of it)

Comment: It's called "XBox live", but it's just some Microsoft thing. But it's also not just a Microsoft account. It's not only needlessly complicated, but also badly named. Also I have no idea what kinds of accounts you need for Bedrock Edition. Welcome to Microsoft!